# Is it possible to make a web-app which works offline?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I know I could utilize client-side storage, cookies, WebSQL to make an app independent of the internet if the tablet/phone went offline for a bit. But at the end of the day if the user refreshes the browser, the site will try to load the HTML/CSS/JS and it's going to fail to load. I haven't been keeping up on HTML5 enhancements in the last year so I'm wondering if something like this exists. For instance specifically telling the browser to cache the static assets and use them again upon reload unless newer versions exist.

NOTE: I'm only interested in how to allow the page to go through a reload with the site offline if such thing exists.

Comment: If you are using JS or CSS files that are hosted on some web server (internet), you won't be able to load them. To do that you can dowload them locally to the client (user) computer

Comment: if you run your server with localhost, i am sure it will work offline

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_app_cache.asp

Comment: [I might have found something helpful](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/workshop-making-it-work-offline)

Comment: Who is the wiseass that downvoted this?!! This is a perfectly good query towards finding good techniques to serve pages faster!

Comment: @Sidmeister I didn't downvote this personally, but I'm sure the person who did probably did so because this question isn't exactly appropriate for SO due to its broad nature and also since this can be answered with a simple Google search

Comment: You'll want [ServiceWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API) once they're available in your [target environments](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers).

Comment: @NoahFreitas I was basically going to code up a service layer which works like ServiceWorkers but if the user refreshes the browser it's going to try and re-fetch the site. What I'm looking for is a way to tell the browser to use the HTML/JS/CSS that's been previously downloaded upon refresh. I know it's a crazy idea but I was hoping someone had figured it out.

Comment: @Corey service workers and app cache (@Nick Zuber's comment) are really your only options in the browser.

Comment: @NoahFreitas Yup. I tested out some stuff with App Cache just now and it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that @NickZuber has answer my question with his link. The thing I was looking for is

[Application Cache](http://caniuse.com/#search=App%20cach)

- Works on most (90%+) modern browsers Best suited for storing
  application code
- The only option to reliably load a website from nothing offline
- Can storage a significant amount of data (50mb+)
- Very difficult use without causing unintended consequences for most
  websites

[Here is a working example of it in action](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm). You can essentially turn off your internet, hit refresh on the browser, close the browser and re-open it. Whatever you want and the app loads up just fine complete with Images, CSS Styles, and Javascript.

Comment: This approach is deprecated.

Comment: Deprecated how? It currently supported by all major browser versions.

Comment: Appcache didn't work. It failed. It didn't do what people needed. It doesn't support basic offline scenarios. That's why it was replaced with Service Workers, which provide a full-fledged, app-level offline experience. Deprecated does not mean not supported; many deprecated approaches continue to be supported.